# drag and drop inside nested Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

This is my requirement,

1. I have an item called **`dragItem`** to drag and Drop.
2. I have 2 Divs, **`Outer`** and **`inner`**
3. I need to do in this order - Drag  the dragItem in the outer Div (So that I do some of my functionalities. At this point only the next droppable code will be enabled.) then I again drag the dragItem and drop in inner Div.

The problem I get is when the second time I drag and drop into inner Div, the outer droppable code is getting invoked first and then getting into the inner droppable, as the inner div is inside outer Div.

A similar one I tried Is attached. [check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/njYqA/362/)

So how to rectify this? I need to enable the droppable wherever I drop Item even though it is in multilayered Divs. How to achieve this?

--Thanks In Advance

Comment: same problem for me also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ui `droppable` supports an option called `greedy: true` which will stop the event propagation.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/njYqA/365/)